# what does this check constraint means (NOT [EXIST_code] like '%[^-0-9A-Z_/&$!]%')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

What does this check constraint definition mean?

```
(NOT [EXIST_code] like '%[^-0-9A-Z_/&$!]%')
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation:

```
  NOT LIKE
```

in SQL is used on a column which is of type varchar. Usually, it is used with % which is used to represent any string value, including the null character \0.

Probably have to understand your regex expression and see how the data is being retrieved based on it's exception :)

The regex expr represents this:

Match a single character not present in the list below [^-0-9A-Z_/&$!]:

```
- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
_/&$! matches a single character in the list _/&$! (case sensitive)
```

Comment: yeah i dont understand what the regex means

Comment: hope that helps, it's always a good idea to search up the basics of different regex expression :)

Comment: It's not actually a regex, it's a special `LIKE` pattern matching syntax (which looks like a regex though)